# Sum of convergent power series with increasing degrees is convergent.

Tags: power-series, complex-geometry, absolute-convergence, formal-power-series

I'm contemplating **Exercise 1.1.3** from Greuel, Lossen and Shustin's *Introduction to Singularities and Deformations*. It states

> Let $(f_k)_{k  \in  \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of convergent power series in $\mathbb C\{x_1, \dotsc, x_n\}$ with $\operatorname{ord}(f_{k+1}) > \operatorname{ord}(f_k)$ for all $k$. Show that $\sum_{k \in \mathbb N} f_k$ is a well-defined convergent power series.

For a power series $f = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha x^\alpha$, the order is defined as
$$ \operatorname{ord}(f) = \min \{\, |\alpha| : c_\alpha \neq 0 \,\}.$$

Clearly, $g = \sum_k f_k$ is a well-defined formal power series, since for every multiindex $\alpha \in \mathbb N_0^k$, the term $g_\alpha$ only involves such $f_k$ with $\operatorname{ord}(f_k) \leq |\alpha|$ where $| \alpha| = \alpha_1 + \dotsb + \alpha_n$, and those are finitely many by assumption. But I don't know how to show that $g$ is convergent.

However, I'm not sure if this is even true? For example consider the power series
$$ f_k = \sum_{n = k}^\infty k^n x^n.$$
This is convergent by the ratio test with radius of convergence $r_k = \frac{1}{k}$.
Since $\operatorname{ord}(f_k) = k$, the assumption $\operatorname{ord}(f_{k+1}) > \operatorname{ord}(f_{k})$ is satisfied. But for each $\epsilon > 0$, all but finitely many $f_k$ are divergent in a disc of radius $\epsilon$, so how can we even expect $\sum_k f_k$ to be convergent?

More precisely, the power series here is
$$
g =\sum_{k \in \mathbb N} f_k =  \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \sum_{n \geq k} k^n x^n = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \left( \sum_{k \leq n} k^n \right) x^n.
$$
So by the formel of Cauchy-Hadamard, it has radius of convergence
$$
r = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k \leq n} k^n}} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n^n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0.
$$

Comment: What is the definition of ord$(f)$? I've never heard of it.

Comment: if $f = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha f_\alpha$ is a power series, then $\operatorname{ord}(f) = \min \{ |\alpha| : c_\alpha \neq 0 \}$. So the order is the vanishing order of $f$ at $0$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Of course it should be $f = \sum_{\alpha} c_\alpha x^\alpha$.